# What's a proper way to use pivot_root(2)?

Tags: c, linux

I'm doing a self-research project(I'm trying to create a simple container).
I don't know how to properly use `pivot_root(2)`.

What I did:
1.

```
chdir("/newroot"); 
/*chroot(".");*/ 
pivot_root(".", "."); // errno: EINVAL.
```

2. So far I'm using `chroot()` for the mnt namespace, I've commented out the `chroot()` as it's part of EINVAL errno.
3. I tried to add `printk` into the syscall, well that didn't go as planned.
4. 

```
chdir("/newroot");
pivot_root(".", "putOld"); errno: EINVAL
mount --make-private --bind /newroot /newroot
```

Comment: `printk()` is a kernel function, not used in user-mode code.

Comment: @Barmar I know I inserted the printk() onto the syscall to dump the pivot_root use done by systemd to avoid snooping through source code of random projects. Not sure exactly what went wrong with what I did, but I get kernel panic on the custom kernel.

Comment: From `man 2 pivot_root`: `EINVAL put_old is not underneath new_root` And: `put_old  must be underneath new_root, that is, adding a nonzero number of /.. to the string pointed to by put_old must yield the same directory as new_root.`

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html) presents several requirements on the arguments to `pivot_root()`.  The ones most likely to be causing you trouble are:

> - `new_root` and `put_old` must not be on the same mount as the
>   current root.
>
> [...]
>
> - `new_root` must be a path to a mount point, but can't be "/".  A
>   path that is not already a mount point can be converted into
>   one by bind mounting the path onto itself.
> - The propagation type of the parent mount of new_root and the
>   parent mount of the current root directory must not be
>   `MS_SHARED`

See [mount_namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) for a discussion of mount propagation type, and pay special attention to the NOTES section.

Note also that it doesn't make much sense to me to specify the same path for `new_root` and `put_old`.  I think that is effectively a no-op as far as the filesystem view is concerned, because you mount the original filesystem root directly on top of the new filesystem root.  I would expect `put_old` to instead designate a distinct directory somewhere underneath the new root.

Comment: I haven't fixed the problem yet, turned out it's more than just about put_old being in new_root.

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised, @JakubStrzelecki.  `put_old` being in `new_root` is not even among the issues highlighted in this answer.  I do mention at the end that *it doesn't make sense* for them to be the same directory, but that doesn't mean that that combination shouldn't work.

Comment: The only thing that have caught my eye is it implies the parent mount also can't be MS_SHARED. So even though I've bind mounted a directory I pivot_root into MS_PRIVATE the parent mount "/" is still shared.

Comment: @JakubStrzelecki, the docs don't seem to say so explicitly, but it is plausible that the function might want absolute paths for `new_root` and `put_old`.